# Cookie for Popup Handling Across Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

the code below displays a popup after 60 seconds on page load.  It stores a cookie that prevents the popup being shown more than once. The cookie then expires when the session ends.

However, the popup doesn't fire if you browse multiple pages.  I need the popup to fire when navigating the site on 60 seconds, not just show on the entry page on 60 seconds, if that makes sense?

Here's the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       if($.cookie('form-cookie') == null)
       {
           setTimeout(function(){
           $('#form').modal('show');
           }, 60000);
           $.cookie('form-cookie', 'str');
       }
       else
      {
          $("div#form.modal").css('display','none');
      }
      });
 }
```

Thanks for any help, I'm new to this...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply save a cookie, set the cookie value to a timestamp (in seconds) and then check if cookie exists and if the current timestamp is < 60 compared with current timestamp.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
       if($.cookie('form-cookie') == null)
       {
           setTimeout(function(){
           $('#form').modal('show');
           }, 60000);
           $.cookie('form-cookie', seconds);
       }
       else
      {
          var diff=seconds-$.cookie('form-cookie')*1;
          if (diff<60){
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('#form').modal('show');
             }, 60000); //only for the time remaining, use diff*1000
          }else{
              $("div#form.modal").css('display','none');
          }
      }
      });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get this to work.  When I browse the site the popup doesn't show.  The cookie is still set immediately on page load.  Not sure if this is correct or not?